# How run custom command ( run bash script ) before NX command?

Tags: nrwl-nx, nx-monorepo

I would like to execute a .sh script before running the "serve" command. Is there an option in Nx similar to "before"?

So, I want to run a bash script when I execute npx nx run projectName:storybook or projectName:serve, before the main command starts.

```
 "projectName": {
      "root": "path/testPath",
      "sourceRoot": "path/testPath",
      "projectType": "application",
      "targets": {
        "serve": {
           ...
          },
          "configurations": {
             ...
          },
          "before": ["nx run testTest:alex"]
        },
        "storybook": {
          "executor": "@nrwl/storybook:storybook",
          "options": { 
            ...
          },
          "configurations": {
            "ci": {
              "quiet": true
            }
          },
          "before": ["nx run testTest:alex"]
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All targets support a `dependsOn` property ([see docs](https://nx.dev/reference/project-configuration#dependson)). This will ensure that another target is run before your target starts up.

```json
"targets": {
   "serve": {
      "exectuor": "@nx/whatever",
      "dependsOn": ["some-other-target"],
      //...
   },

   "some-other-target": {
      "command": "./path/to/some/script.sh"
   }
}
```

With this setup NX will run `nx run my-project:some-other-target` first when `nx run my-project:serve` is called.

---

Alternatively, you could move the serve target to some other name, and make a new serve target that runs the commands you need.

Perhaps like:

```json
"targets": {
   "serve": {
      "executor": "nx:run-commands",
      "options": {
         "commands": [
            "nx run my-app:some-other-target"
            "nx run my-app:serve-web",
         ],
         "parallel": false
      }
   },

   "serve-web": {
      "exectuor": "@nx/whatever",
      //...
   },

   "some-other-target": {
      "command": "./path/to/some/script.sh"
   }
}
```

Now `serve` is a target that invokes two other targets in a specific order.